# Can you return the list element that gives the min/max value of some function using a single list comprehension?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of objects and a function foo which takes one of those objects and returns a float value. I want to find the *object* that returns the minimum value, not the minimum value itself.

At the moment, I am doing this in two steps:

1. Calculating the minimum value:

   ```
   min_value = min([foo(x) for x in my_list])
   ```
2. Finding the first item in the list that returns that value:

   ```
   result = [x for x in my_list if foo(x) == min_value][0]
   ```

Is there a pythonic way to do this in a single line that doesn't involve looping twice?

Comment: `min` takes a `key` you can use - `min(my_list, key=foo)`.